# How to use comtrend router to create NAT and use same public IP for all LAN devices

Tags: router, nat

I think the title says it all.

I would like to use my Comtrend router in a way that all devices connected to the router (ethernet and WiFi) use the same public IP for going to the outside world. Is this even possible?

What is required for creating such a private network?

I am a bit confused by so many settings on the router. Thanks for any Hint!

Answer (score 0):

This is a router given to you by your ISP?  If so, you dont need to change anything.   All the devices on the LAN use the public IP assigned to the router.  The NAT should be set automatically.

Comment: It is a router that was given by an ISP, BUT now i am in a student home like place with pre-installed internet with external "routing control". I plug the router into the ethernet. By the private network, I want to avoid that there is only a limited number of devices that can be connected.